# Convert Programm, where I can cut now and convert later

Tags: video, video-editing

I have multiple TV records (.ts) and I want to convert them into avi, cut the beginng and split the rest into two parts.

I have tried Freemake VideoConverter and XMedia Recode, but they don't offer these features.

There are several movies in on file: AABBBBBBBBBBCCCCCCCCCDDD

A and D are overhead. I want to delete these parts B and C are two different movies. I want them in seperate files.

And: I want to cut them in "one session", save the marks for "cutting" and "splitting" and convert movie for movie whenever the PC is in idle. Keep in mind, that I want to shut down the PC sometimes, so I NEED a "save" function

Comment: What format are the recordings in currently? Transport Stream (`.ts`)? Then the Java based [ProjectX](https://linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/ProjectX) might be a good fit (I've used that ages ago when I still was cutting and compining my TV recordings ;)

Comment: @Izzy Yes, they are .ts. I will give it a try and give feedback soon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the past, I've used **[ProjectX](https://linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/ProjectX)** for this purpose. This software is written in Java (and thus available cross-platform). You can set markers where to cut things out, and have it process your project later. Of course you can also save your marks, so nothing gets lost:

[image: ProjectX] [image: ProjectX]
<sup>*ProjectX* (source: [LinuxTV.org](https://linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/ProjectX); click images for larger variants)</sup>

As the linked page describes, you can even run it from the command line, which would match your use case perfectly: first use the GUI to set your marks, then schedule the processing e.g. via `at` or `cron`.

With your constellation of ABCD, cutting off A and D is easy. But storing B and C in different files might require multiple runs (I've never tried that in one run, as I usually only had constellations of ABBBABBBA (one movie interrupted by advertizements – or the other way round with advertizements interrupted by movie sequences, depending on the point of view ;)

Note that while the homepage states the latest release being from 3/2011 (which SF shows as being from 5/2013), there are [two forks at Github](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=project-x+dvb&type=Repositories&ref=searchresults). So if you're familiar with Java and can compile your own `.jar`, those might be worth a look.